# ListView depopulates after I start a new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I'm new to making ListViews with CustomAdapters (this is my first attempt) and I'm not sure how well/efficient I made it. So what I'm trying to do is get the name that is highlighted red in the ListView. I do this with the getSelectedName method. However, in the BuildInput class, when I intent to the MainActivity and intent back to the BuildInput class, the ListView is completely gone. Since the ListView is gone, so is the highlighted red name and the getSelectedName method doesn't work.

How do I keep the ListView from depopulating when I intent to the MainActivity?

```
public class Names {
    public String name;
    public Names(){
        super();
    }
    public Names(String name){
        super();
        this.name = name;
```

-

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Names>{

private ArrayList<Names> items;
private TextView tvHolder;
private String selectedName = "";

public CustomAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Names> items){
    super(context, 0, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Names names = getItem(position);
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_namechoices, parent, false);

    }
    Names nm = items.get(position);
    if (nm != null){
        final TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameItem);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (tvHolder != null) {
                    tvHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    tvHolder = tv;
                    selectedName = tv.getText().toString();
                } else {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    tvHolder = tv;
                    selectedName = tv.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameItem);
    tv.setText(names.name);
    return convertView;
}

public String getSelectedName(){
    return selectedName;
}
}
```

-

```
public class BoardInput extends Activity {

private EditText mUserInput;
private Button mConfirm;
private Button mReady;
private ArrayList<Names> arrayOfNames = new ArrayList<Names>();
private CustomAdapter adapter;
private ListView listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boardinput);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(BoardInput.this, arrayOfNames);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    mUserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    mConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mUserInput.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else {
                arrayOfNames.add(new Names(mUserInput.getText().toString()));
                mUserInput.setText("");
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(BoardInput.this, arrayOfNames);
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
    });
    mReady = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ready);
    mReady.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (adapter.getSelectedName().isEmpty()){
                Log.d("NULL","NULL");
            }
            else{
                Log.d("BoardInput", adapter.getSelectedName());
                Intent i = new Intent(BoardInput.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

This is what the BoardInput class creates:

[image]

You type a name in the edittext and clicking confirm will add the name to the listview and clear the edittext. When you click on a name in the listview, it will highlight red and that's the name I need to use in my MainActivity class.

Comment: First time you are setting an empty adapter as this arrayOfNames array is empty & in else case don't call setAdapter instead do this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: delete this from else listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

Answer (score 2):

I have made some Changes in your code:

```
public class BoardInput extends Activity {

private EditText mUserInput;
private Button mConfirm;
private Button mReady;
private List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Names> arrayOfNames = new ArrayList<Names>();
private CustomAdapter adapter;
private ListView listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boardinput);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(BoardInput.this, arrayOfNames);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    mUserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    mConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mUserInput.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else {
                arrayOfNames.add(new Names(mUserInput.getText().toString()));
                mUserInput.setText("");
    **Edited**:
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listview.invalidateView();
            }

        }
    });
    mReady = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ready);
    mReady.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (adapter.getSelectedName().isEmpty()){
                Log.d("NULL","NULL");
            }
            else{
                Log.d("BoardInput", adapter.getSelectedName());
                Intent i = new Intent(BoardInput.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: After using the edited code, the adapter.getSelectedName would stay as empty, so I couldn't go to the MainActivity. I removed the if statements just to test if the ListView would depopulate if I go to MainActivity and back and it did. I editted my post a little bit by adding a picture of what the BoardInput class creates and added more detail on what the class does and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: May be the issue still remain present but the things I mentioned you were doing them wrong totally

Answer (score 1):

When you intent to the MainActivity and not finish the BoardInputActivity the ListView will still exist when the MainActivity is closed. But when you intent to the BoardInputActivity everything will be reconstructed including the adapter.

Comment: Is there a way I can intent to BoardInputActivity and prevent it from reconstructing everything?

Comment: I think you should save your adaptermodel to a database. When your view gets constructed, get all of the stored information and rebuild the adapter

Comment: Is there a specific/recommended method of saving my adapter to a database? I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: You need to store your Names class, look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)